# How to open syslog files in Python

Tags: python-3.x, logging, argv, syslog, sys

I am trying an assignment to open a syslog for a server program (called ticky) that creates logs and errors and then assign the errors to a dictionary and export to a csv file to sort and host to a webpage,

I am unsure of how to access syslog files, as the course only went into sys.argv and I don't know if this can be used or if I need to figure out how to use syslog module. Once the log is opened, the regex will pull the error message and add it to the dictionary, either creating a new entry or adding value to an existing key.

Am I on the right track?

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python3

    import re
    import sys

    errors = {}

    # log line format
    # Jun 1 11:06:48 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR: Connection to DB failed (username)

    logfile = sys.argv[1]
    # NOTE: Check to find correct log file
    with open(logfile) as f:
        for line in f:
            if "ERROR:" not in line:
                continue
            regex_error = r"ERROR: (\d+) "
            """searches for error messages"""
            error = re.search(regex_error, line)
            if error is None:
                continue
            name = error[1]
            errors[name] = errors.get(name, 0) + 1
```

Comment: The [`sys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html) and [`syslog`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/syslog.html) are two completely separate packages. Looking at the docks syslog is for writing not reading syslog files, so you can probably just open the files with `open` and parse the content form there

Comment: So I can cut logfile = sys.argv[1] and change logfile in open() to the file name or location filename like 'sys/log/logfile.txt'

Comment: unless you are passing the path to the target log file via command line arguments then yes you can replace the `sys.argv[1]` to `sys/log/logfile.txt'. It would probably be a good idea to use an absolute path especially if you will be running you program directly from an IDE